# Small Scale load levelling

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, job-scheduling

I have a series of jobs which need to be done; no dependencies between jobs. I'm looking for a tool which will help me distribute these jobs to machines. The only restriction is that each machine should run one job at a time only. I'm trying to maximize throughput, because the jobs are not very balanced. My current hacked together shell scripts are less than efficient as I pre-build the per-machine job-queue, and can't move jobs from the queue of a heavily loaded machine to one which is waiting, having already finished everything.

Previous suggestions have included SLURM which seems like overkill, and even more overkill LoadLeveller.

GNU Parallel looks like almost exactly what I want, but the remote machines don't speak SSH; there's a custom job launcher used (which has no queueing capabilities). What I'd like is Gnu Parallel where the machine can just be substituted into a shell script on the fly just before the job is dispatched.

So, in summary:

- List of Jobs + List of Machines which can accept: Maximize throughput. As close to shell as possible is preferred.

Worst case scenario something can be hacked together with bash's lockfile, but I feel as if a better solution must exist somewhere.

Comment: Have you consider using the shell built-in jobs?  Something like while # jobs >= maxjobs sleep .1; command &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your jobs are in a text file `jobs.tab` looking like

```
/path/to/job1
/path/to/job2
...
```

Create `dispatcher.sh` as something like

```
mkfifo /tmp/jobs.fifo
while true; do
  read JOB
  if test -z "$JOB"; then 
    break 
  fi
  echo -n "Dispatching job $JOB .."
  echo $JOB >> /tmp/jobs.fifo
  echo ".. taken!"
done
rm /tmp/jobs.fifo
```

and run one instance of

```
dispatcher.sh < jobs.tab
```

Now create `launcher.sh` as

```
while true; do
  read JOB < /tmp/jobs.fifo
  if test -z "$JOB"; then
    break
  fi

  #launch job $JOB on machine $0 from your custom launcher

done
```

and run one instance of `launcher.sh` per target machine (giving the machine as first and only argument)

Comment: See, I knew there had to be a simple choice. Thanks! I'll give that a try ASAP, but it looks good on inspection. I'm accepting based on that alone.

Comment: So on my machine, it looks like there's some odd edge case behaviour at termination. By and large, everything works fine, but at the end the launchers will all hang waiting for input from the fifo. 

In my case, I've worked around it by sending a sentinel value ("quit") to each of the launchers (checking process list for launchers which exist).

Comment: TBH I was not 100% sure about the `rm /tmp/jobs.fifo` without any checks, but it worked in my simple test case. Sentinel is an excellent and robust idea.

Comment: Also, while it doesn't cause a lot of problems for me, a warning to anyone wanting to use this: Fifo pipes are not always atomically read-nor written in all UNIXes, so some jobs can read garbage. (at least this is what I've been finding). I'll be working on a better solution... someday.

Comment: @Keggart if you run into this, try to use a SysV Message Queue instead of the FIFO, this is guaranteed to be atomical. As an alternative use `netcat -l` at the dispatcher and `netcat` plain vanilla on the launcher. Same idea, different transport medium

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel supports your own ssh command. So this should work:

```
function my_submit { echo On host $1 run command $3; }
export -f my_submit
parallel -j1 -S "my_submit server1,my_submit server2" my_command ::: arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks like another good answer. Just curious, is there documentation on the args this submit function takes? I couldn't find it in the [manpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html)

Comment: The bash function 'submit' is defined above. It is not in any man page. Change the function 'submit' to fit your needs. I changed the name to my_submit to stress that it is defined by you.

Comment: So that I followed. What I'm understanding from this is that under the covers, instead of doing `ssh server1 ... my_command arg1` it's instead going to do `my_submit server1 ... my_command args`. What I was curious is what is that second arg `...`, and could I do cool things with it?

Comment: If you are curious what hides in $2, then try echoing it in my_submit. Unfortunately neither $1, $2 nor $3 is guaranteed to stay the same in future versions. While it is unlikely they will change, it is not guaranteed.